# line break in excel datatable

Tags: excel, database

How can I define a line break in a datatable excel when it is exploited?

https://jsfiddle.net/pa9q14mb/6/

At the time of exporting the excel the box shows it

```
-TEXT TEXT TEXT -TEXT TEXT TEXT -TEXT TEXT TEXT -TEXT TEXT TEXT
```

But I would like it this way in the excel

```
   -TEXT TEXT TEXT 
   -TEXT TEXT TEXT 
   -TEXT TEXT TEXT 
   -TEXT TEXT TEXT
```

I would like to know if there is the possibility of doing that and I was  looking at some examples with the `exportOptions` function, but without results. regards

Comment: Same question has been asked in the DataTables forums here: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/53919/line-break-when-exporting-to-excel Have you tried anything w/that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you're already setting your export options, you need to do something like this:

```
return column === 5 ?
       data.replace(/<br>/g,String.fromCharCode(10)) :
       data;
```

`<br>` appears in your DataTables cell, so you need to convert that to a carriage return (ascii code 10), which is what Excel expects for a new line.